# Module not found: Can't resolve 'bignumber.js'

Tags: truffle

I'm using truffle unbox react to bootstrap my dapp. Whenever I run the client end of the application with `npm run start`, I see that React fails to compile with the following error:

Module not found: Can't resolve '`bignumber.js`' in '`/node_modules/truffle-contract/lib`'

It would be great if someone could advise what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Can be multiple reasons:

- package was not saved in `package.json`*. need to run `npm install -s bignumber.js` in order to fix it
- old version of nodejs, can't read(process) `package-lock.json` properly. you need to remove the file and run `npm install`